# Оптимизировать mySQL запрос

Tags: mysql, index, inner-join, explain

Подскажите Оптимально ли составлен запрос:

```
 SELECT *
 FROM (
     (`tbl_projects`
 LEFT JOIN `tbl_files`
     ON ((`file_isforType` = 1) AND `file_isforID`=`proj_uid`) )
 INNER JOIN `tbl_users`
     ON `proj_InitiatorUsrID` = `usr_UID` )
 ORDER BY `file_uid` DESC LIMIT 0 , 15
```

---

Я прогонял его через EXPLAIN и  обнаружил что несмотря на все мои
 усилия  в первой строчке индекс не используется!(

насколько я помню из учебников это плохо. и тип перебора = all -

> худший из всех возможных означающий итерацию по каждойбожей записи в
>    этой таблице.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hwvv7.png)
     По формуле rows получается   4x1x1 итераций на строку хотя ожидалось бы  1x1x[0..files_count].

То что у меня получилось - это нормально или плохо или хорошо. Я что
 то не вьеду)

Пожалуйста подкиньте цитат для вразумления или Ваших личных
 профипояснений почему тут что да как..

---

view  ([image: https://i.ibb.co/6B5YD8g/x2.png])
кспорт sql прилагается
   [tbl_users](https://vk.com/doc53763852_487202011)

[tbl_files.sql](https://vk.com/doc53763852_487202017)

[tbl_projects.sql](https://vk.com/doc53763852_487202026)

---

Идея базы простая. задания.

Юзер публикует задание. К заданию подключает или не подключает фотки.

каждое задание имеет юзера-создателя каждое фото имеет
 задание-хозяина.

не каждый юзер обязан создавать задание не каждое задание имеет файлы.

---

связь такая на один проект - один юзер - на один проект - от 0 до X
 файлов

Результат выполнения запроса образно говоря такой:

```
 proj1 | user1 | photo1
 proj1 | user1 | photo2
 proj1 | user1 | photo3

 proj2 | user1 | photo4
 proj2 | user1 | photo5

 proj3 | user2 | photo6

 proj4 | user1 | null

 proj5 | user1 | photo7
 proj5 | user1 | photo8
 proj6 | user2 | null
```

php код идет сверху вниз строчка за строчкой и соединяет всё это в
 html

```
 proj1 - user1 - 3 photos
 proj2 - user1 - 2 photos
 proj3 - user2 - 1 photo
 proj4 - user1 -  no photos
 proj5 - user1 - 2 photos
 etc
```

table_files is build in next logic:

```
 file_uid | file_ownerID | file_isforType| file_isforID
 file_uid PRIMARY AI
 file_ownerID  reference to PRIMARY at table_users
 file_isforType- smallint 1..9
 indicates type of THING which this file was attached to.
  eg
 1 = _TheProject as project photo
 2 = _TheUserProfile as users photo
 3 = _TheMessage as attachment

 file_ResourceID - unique id of that very thing, whose type specified in file_isforType.
```

eg

```
 if (file_isWhatfor=_TheProject) AND (file_ResourceID=3)    ->> to the proj#3
 if (file_isWhatfor=_TheUserProfile) AND (file_ResourceID=3)    ->> to the user#3
 if (file_isWhatfor=_TheMessage) AND (file_ResourceID=3)    ->> to the msg#3
```

Comment: А вы уверены, что вам нужна именно такая сортировка результата ? ведь files клеится по left join, т.к. его может и не быть. Т.е. вы хотите что бы у вас в начале оказались те у кого файл есть, а уже после (если влезут в 15) те у кого его нет. Что бы _перед_ сортировкой узнать, а есть файл или нет БД необходимо провести эту проверку для _всех_ записей proj. Лимит уже никакой роли не играет, так как не обработав все записи и не отсортировав их, невозможно понять какие 15 взять. Так что для заданного запроса план практически единственно возможный.

Comment: НО когда у вас в БД всего 4 записи в основной таблице - то говорить вообще не о чем, они заведомо лежат в одном блоке и БД отлично понимает, что поднять с диска она сможет за одну операцию все записи, а значит пытаться еще отдельно поднимать с диска страницы какого либо индекса, указатели из которых приведут в этот единственный блок,  вообще смысла не имеет.  На таких малых объемах данных БД могла вообще взять full scan для всех таблиц и это было бы нормальным подходом

Comment: Отсюда мораль: 1. проверяйте планы выполнения на приличных объемах данных (хотя бы от 1000 записей), иначе они не информативны. 2. Не пугайтесь full scan первой таблицы запроса, это довольно частое явление в отсутствие дополнительного фильтра строк (например в where). 3. Имейте ввиду, что full scan таблицы в несколько раз быстрее работы по индексу не первичного ключа, когда надо поднять более 10% всех данных (никогда ни один из сценариев нельзя считать "самым худшим", у всего есть свои плюсы и минусы). 4. Сортировка имеет значение для плана

Comment: спасибо огромное за все три комментария! очень ободряюще было прочесть глубокий ответ.
особенно за третий комментарий.
и за второй.
по поводу первого - тоже
и вправду я ошибся - 
было вначале 
projects (join users) 
join files on projects. Сейчас поправлю...